# How do I use the set command to find directories in my path?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am taking a linux class this semester and one of the questions on a lab is:

Use the set command to find out all directories in your path.

Normally, I would just use `$PATH` to find out the directories in my path.  But, obviously the question is asking us to use set.  I have never used set before and went to do `man set` to find out a little bit about the command, but, to my surprise my shell (bash) didn't have an entry for set.  However, I see that there is a set man page here http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html So that is my first question: Why isn't there an entry when I use the command `man set`?

I posted on a discussion board that if i just type `set` it spits out a bunch of function stuff that looks like info from `rails` which I have installed on my machine.  No idea whats going on there..  My professor explained that set is a "built in" function which is why it might not have documentation in the man pages.

After looking at the set documentation online a little bit, I still have no idea how I can get it to spit out my `$PATH` and after doing a little research I haven't found anything that really explains `set` well in the context that I need to use it

To be clear I am not simply seeking an answer here, a general explanation pointing me in the right direction would be very helpful.

TL;DR

1. Why can I find a man entry online for `set` but when I use the command `man set` no documentation is available in my terminal.
2. What might be a general way to use `set` to find the directories in my `PATH`

Thanks!

edit: The full question:

5. Use the set command to find out all of the directories in your “PATH.” You will get a lot of data and you will need to pipe to another command to filter out just what you want. Please note that PATH is capitalized. Paste or type those directories below. You will get a bunch of data so see if you can dig through it to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a manual entry for `set`: the one derived from the [POSIX standard's specification of `set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25). To view it, you must have `manpages-posix-dev` installed (well, `manpages-posix` would do, but you might as well install both). Then you can do:

   ```
   man 1posix set
   ```

   Or visit the online Ubuntu manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/set.1posix
   When possible, do prefer the manpages from that site, since it reflects the manpages that can be made available on your Ubuntu system. Other sites may vary markedly.
2. What your prof probably intended was that you would use the [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grep.1) command in combination with `set`. This is not the Right Way™ for a few reasons. `grep` can be used to filter out lines from the output of another command, or from a file. And `set`'s default output is ... every variable set in your shell and their values, including `PATH`.

Lastly, you forgot to click [*Next*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifying-Shell-Behavior.html#Modifying-Shell-Behavior) while viewing the Bash documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into this info.  This is always a comforting first sentence "This builtin is so complicated that it deserves its own section." :)

Comment: @MichaelJames you're welcome. But I should tell you that `set`'s default behaviour is to print a list of *every* variable set in your shell, including `PATH`. Since there are so many, `PATH` gets lost in the output. So the manpage may not be as useful here.

Comment: Eureka!  So that is what is happening when I just say `set` I have a whole bunch of environment variables.  Now, how to go about piping the information from path...

Comment: @MichaelJames what are the odds of you saying ["piping"](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html)?

Comment: hahaha no I must admit I do know what piping is.. just not sure what to do in this particular case.  We aren't supposed to use regex yet..Learning about grep now.  I think that's my ticket.

Comment: @MichaelJames Check out the example in that page, if it helps. `grep` doesn't have to be about regex - it can use fixed strings just as well - any fixed string is a regex, after all.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that `set` is a shell builtin: that means that its documentation is in the manual page for bash (in the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section) rather than in a manpage of its own. More simply, you can get basic usage information by typing

```
help set
```

from the shell prompt. As to using it to "find out all directories in your path" it would be useful to have some context - I can't really imagine what your instructor/teacher might be intending, aside from perhaps using `set -- $PATH` (with a suitable `IFS` field separator) to assign path elements to the shell's positional parameters, and then print them.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about `help set` I have edited my question to include the full question from the assignment to provide context as you requested.